# Restrict Cross Domain Ajax request

Tags: javascript, browser, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, httpresponse

I have web application (In java) where I need to restrict Cross Domain request through Ajax call in any browser (Including IE restricting XDomainRequest object) through jquery or simple javaScript ajax call.

My ultimate aim it to restrict it while the call is made either through some browser setting or setting response header so it wont make the call in the first point itself.

If same-orgin policy is a solution pls do explain how it is addressed.

Thanks and regards,
Oceanvijai

Comment: What are you asking? It is not clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control which domains you accept AJAX requests from via the [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-hea) response header. If the header is missing, only requests from the same domain are allowed.

**Update:** if you want to disallow even the initiation of AJAX requests, you could try [`X-Content-Security-Policy:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Security/CSP/Using_Content_Security_Policy)`xhr-src 'none'`, but I can't imagine any situation where that would be useful. Maybe you could explain the situation in a little more detail?

Comment: Thanks you 4 the reply , But this Access-Control-Allow-Origin flag in response is validated when the ajax call comes back from the requesting server (remote domain) right ? I need to prevent the ajax request itself so it wont post any values from the local domain to remote domain server.

Comment: I am not sure if this entire situation is possible but I had a strange idea that what if the some xss attacker put a malicious code in the victim page trying to steal some sensitive info from this local page and post it on some other server though ajax calls.....

Comment: @Oceanvijai: Content Security Policy would block most XSS attacks (e.g. local `<script>` tags and `javascript:` URIs are not executed when it is in use), and it can block most methods of talking home (AJAX, script tag, invisible iframe or image). I don't think you can stop an XSS attack from sending stolen data by `window.location` or `window.open`, however. (Also, CSP only works in Firefox 4 for now.)